# .htaccess that protects roots folder but not subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

From Nginx is really simple to do, but with Apache I can't configure this security on my dev server.
I need to protect with password the root folder of all sites and instead give free access to all subfolders. In thats way, after authenticate I can view all listed subfolder, but my customers can't access to root folder.

There is any way with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/[^/]+/" NO_AUTH

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```

This will password protect only root directory files but will allow full access to all the sub directories.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. I need to protect /dev/ with password (that is also a subdomain dev.mysite.com) and allow /dev/foo/, ecc

Comment: Can you tell me what is the full URL that you want to protect with password?

Comment: dev.mysite.com/ (same of mysite.com/dev/)

Comment: If you enter `http://example.com/dev` it should show auth dialog. Also is `/dev` a real directory?

Comment: For example http://dev.federicoliva.info/2014_architetturaecosostenibile.it/ should be accessible without login

Comment: I tested **exact this code** and getting No auth dialog when URI is `/2014_architetturaecosostenibile.it/`

Comment: In your server? What can be the cause?

Comment: I changed the regex to give access to subfolders also without ending "/". Sorry, it works fine!